# Why does my program continuously loop?

Tags: c++, try-catch

I'm a cis221 student, and I've been assigned a piece of homework I simply cannot figure out...

The code below is the overloaded input operator for my "Fraction" class.

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Fraction& fract)
{
     cout << "Enter the whole number part for the fraction ";
     in >> fract.Whole;
     cout << "Enter the Numerator ";
     in >> fract.Numerator;
     cout << "Enter a Denominator ";
     in >> fract.Denominator;
     try
     {
         if (fract.Denominator == 0)
             throw(FractionException(fract, "Deno input was 0, setting to 1"));
     }
     catch(FractionException e)
     {
         fract.Denominator = 1;
         e.DisplayMessage();
     }
    fract.reduceFraction();
    return in;
}
```

Which is called in main.

```
void main()
{
    //Declarations
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int i = 0;
    Fraction fract[4];
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cin >> fract[i];
    }
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout << fract[i];
    }
}
```

From what I understand, this code should execute perfectly; however, the code continuously loops. This is true even if the exception is never thrown.

I've put a watch on the loop control var "i" and literally watched it count from 0 to 4... I have NO idea what's wrong...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you 100% positive this is your actual code? Which compiler are you using? I ask because I would have expected a compile-time error because your main() returns void rather than int.

Comment: I know most people return int, but Microsoft 2010 lets me return void

Comment: Fair enough. But [it's better to be in the habit of returning int](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.3)

Comment: You sent me to a "newbie questions" page? Now I feel even worse :P

Comment: :P Sorry...for what it's worth, it's THE newbie questions page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Fraction fract[4];
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
```

That's no good. Use `Fraction fract[5]` and you won't be overwriting random memory.

Comment: Now that's strange... I could have swore that it would only loop 4 times... Well, that's stupid of me :)

Comment: What do you mean... eagle eyes?

Comment: I meant, "Well spotted, Erik."